# set session - custom variable to store user id

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to store user id in custom session variable and use it (read) in trigger procedures to authorize user actions. I found something like this:

```
set session "myapp.user" = '12345';
...
SELECT current_setting('myapp.user');
```

and it seems to work - I thought that "myapp.user" should be declared in .conf file but it seems that I can create session variables on the fly (I didn't change .conf file at all).

Is there any disadvantage of doing like this?

Comment: I think the restriction that `myapp.user` has to be declared in `postgresql.conf` was removed in 9.2 or 9.1

Comment: It's a reasonable way to do things so long as the user isn't allowed to run arbitrary SQL (in which case they could just set a different user ID). It's a bit of a hacky workaround for PostgreSQL's lack of true session variables but I'm not aware of any significant issues with it. BTW, please **link to any relevant prior questions/answers you used as a reference**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before version 9.2, you needed to add your custom class variable to [`custom_variable_classes` parameter in `postgresql.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-custom.html), like:

```
custom_variable_classes = 'myapp'
```

In [9.2, this requirement has been removed](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-2.html#AEN112374):

> **Remove the custom_variable_classes parameter (Tom Lane)**
>
> The checking provided by this setting was dubious. Now any setting can
>   be prefixed by any class name.

So, since 9.2 you can just set your custom class variable as you are doing currently, no need to worry about changing `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Postgres 12.6 doesn't allow this. It raises an error if the param is missing from postgresql.conf. SQL Error [42704]:  ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter

Answer (score 2):

For cases like this I like to create a plperl function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION session_store(key text,val text DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
my ($k,$v)=@_;
die "key cannot be NULL\n" unless defined $k;
if (defined $v) {
    $_SHARED{session_store}{$k}=$v;
    return undef;
}
return exists $_SHARED{session_store}{$k}?$_SHARED{session_store}{$k}:undef;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plperl VOLATILE;
```

The advantage of this is that it works in sql statements too, for example:

```
select session_store('user',12345::text);
insert into mytable(userid) values(session_store('user')::integer);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to store the user ID, see [How to get the OS user ID in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194343/how-to-get-os-user-in-postgres)

It's pretty simple, and requires no custom configuration.