# How to read configuration option into variable?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to read configuration option as TEXT but SHOW statement is strange because it does not return any rows.

```
create or replace function get_param()
returns text as $$  
begin
  return query show custom.param; -- does not work, because show does not return setof 
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

set custom.param = 'custom value';
select get_param() as param;
```

Is there any other way of doing this?

---

Actually I found answer in a question asked by me :) [set session - custom variable to store user id](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97095/set-session-custom-variable-to-store-user-id) :

```
SELECT current_setting('custom.param');
```

Comment: Please self answer instead of adding the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `current_setting()`, `SHOW` is workable in this context, it's just a matter of returning a scalar rather than a set. Your function slightly fixed to work would be:

```
create or replace function get_param()
returns text as $$  
declare v text;
begin
  SHOW custom.param INTO v;
  return v;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

However this form does not seem to offer any advantage over calling directly `current_setting()`, so it's probably not worth creating such functions.