# How to send a parameter to a trigger function from an external resource

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql

I have a trigger that executes before delete to audit changes in tables. The problem I have is that one of the fields I save in the `xtable_audit` table is the user id (of an user table) that is used in the web application. How can I send that external `iduser` from the web application to the trigger function when a delete occurs in any table that has that trigger?

Comment: I think [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97095/set-session-custom-variable-to-store-user-id) is the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `set_config()` and `current_setting()` functions for that. In the application just after establishing the database connection you call something like

```
select set_config('myapp.app_user','johnny',false);
```

to set a custom configuration variable for the session. In the trigger you then use

```
select into v_actualuser current_setting('myapp.app_user');
```

to retrieve the value.

[This blog post](http://frefo.blogspot.ca/2009/04/session-variables-in-postgresql.html) even has a sample trigger for your viewing pleasure.